# Google Checkbox Script Explained

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering if anyone could explain, at a more granular level, what this script is actually doing (defining vars, etc.). I get that the script will hide and show rows based on what checkboxes (cells) are checked. But I'm having a hard time figuring out what specifically what `//align the trigger`, `//crude helper func`, `return v[0]` are doing, and finally `status.forEach(showHideRow(;`

```
function onEdit(e) {

// Replace with the name of your sheet
var sheetName = 'NameofYourSheet';

// Align the trigger to the 4 checkboxes
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != sheetName 
    || e.range.rowStart < 6 || e.range.rowStart > 11 || e.range.columnStart != 3) {
    return;
}

// Get checkbox values
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName),
    status = sh.getRange('C7:C10').getValues();

// Crude helper func
function showHideRow(v, i) {
    // [[row, numberRows]]
    var rows = [[11,3],[14,3],[17,3],[20,2]];

    return v[0]
           ? sh.showRows.apply(sh, rows[i])
           : sh.hideRows.apply(sh, rows[i])
};

status.forEach(showHideRow);
```

As always, happy to answer any questions and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `Array#forEach`, what `.apply` does, and how JavaScript's ASI (automatic semicolon insertion) works? For example, `return v[0]` is not the full statement - the actual statement executed spans 3 lines: `return v[0] ? .... : ....`. It would be more apparent if you highlight your code and press Tab in the Script Editor, as it will then apply syntax-based indentation to help you identify new vs continued statements.

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: I think that question is too broad as it encompases four questions.

The brief answer is that Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript so it could be good idea to spend some time learning about JavaScript, and regarding the code on the question particularly about:

1. statements,
2. line terminator,
3. if statement,
4. expressions and conditionals,
5. the conditional (ternary) operator
6. Array.prototype.forEach